# Install CentOS in a VirtualBox to a Compact Flash and use it on a mini PC

Tags: kernel, centos, compiling, virtualbox, architecture

I got into a very specific situation and want to get to know your opinions.

I have got a mini PC with Intel Atom processor which should run CentOS with an upgraded kernel to 3.x and some applications. Disk is a Compact Flash card connected through SATA to CF adapter.

The overall performance of this mini PC is not suitable for compiling kernel. Installing Centos takes more time & effort too so I decided to do the following:

- mount Compact Flash to VirtualBox on a high-performance PC
- install CentOS and all applications through Virtual Box to the CF card
- compile new kernel through VirtualBox
- get all other settings set
- backup the content of the CF with dd (to be able to reuse it)
- boot mini PC with a finalized OS on the CF

I see two main problems:

- CentOS is installed on a different architecture than it is used on = actually I tried this and it worked
- new kernel is compiled on a different architecture than it is used on = this should not be a problem if I compile the kernel to run on all architectures

Do you see other problems which I should be aware of?

Do you have experience with similar sirtuation?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Your PC has a different architecture to the atom?

Comment: No, both are 64bit. But I do not compile kernel on my PC directly but I use VirtualBox to install & run CentOS and to compile kernel.

Comment: VirtualBox *just* uses one of your CPUs; it is still x86-64.

Comment: thank you, I thought that virtual box uses different architecture.